# Sharing web site config across deployment slots using an ARM template

Tags: azure-rm-template

I'm provisioning several webapps in an ARM template, and I'm finding I'm having to have a lot of duplicated code to maintain a single config across multiple deployment slots. Both dependencies and properties have to be duplicated and maintained separately. I looked into using a variable, but a lot of my config is dependent on other resources and cannot be evaluated at the time variables are evaluated.

Ideally I'd like all slots to reference the same 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' object, but I can't see a way to do that. My current deployment script looks like this (although this has been massively simplified, I have significantly more properties in reality)

```
{
  "name": "[variables('siteName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('serverfarm'))]",
    "[resourceid('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('fullEventHubNameSpace'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('siteName'))]": "Resource"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('siteName')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('serverfarm'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "AlwaysOn": true
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "appsettings",
      "type": "config",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('siteName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', variables('appInsightsSiteName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('otherSiteName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/',variables('databaseAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceid('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('fullEventHubNameSpace'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]",
        "KEYVAULT_PATH": "[parameters('keyVaultPath')]",
        "KEYVAULT_SECRET": "[parameters('keyVaultSecret')]",
        "OTHER_SITE": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('otherSiteName'))).hostnames[0]]",
        "DB_KEY": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts'),variables('databaseAccountName')),'2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey]",
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "Staging",
      "type": "slots",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('siteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('siteName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/',variables('databaseAccountName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('otherSiteName'))]",
            "[resourceid('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces', variables('fullEventHubNameSpace'))]",
            "Staging"
          ],
          "properties": {
             "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]",
             "KEYVAULT_PATH": "[parameters('keyVaultPath')]",
             "KEYVAULT_SECRET": "[parameters('keyVaultSecret')]",
             "OTHER_SITE": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('otherSiteName'))).hostnames[0]]",
             "DB_KEY": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts'),variables('databaseAccountName')),'2015-04-08').primaryMasterKey]",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Is there any way to make this template more maintainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can take use of [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) in your Template.

Move the section with your slot to root level in your template and add:

```
"copy": {
    "name": "slotcopy",
    "count": "[length(parameters('webSiteSlots'))]"
},
```

The name propperty shlould look like this:

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('webSiteName'), '/', parameters('webSiteSlots')[copyIndex()].name)]",
```

With this you say that this resource will be a child of the WebSite resource. More information about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#create-multiple-instances-of-a-child-resource).

now you can add a parameter with a complex object array to your template:

```
"webSiteSlots": {
    "type": "array",
    "minLength": 0,
    "defaultValue": []
}
```

in your parameters file you can now set a collection of slots you want to have with some additional values:

```
"webSiteSlots": {
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "Staging",
            "environment": "Production"
        }
    ]
}
```

to use these given values you can do something like this:

```
"properties": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "[parameters('webSiteSlots')[copyIndex()].environment]"
}
```

This should reduce the dublicated code a fair bit.

Greetings,
KirK

Comment: Won't that turn my deployment slot into a separate webapp?

Comment: @IainBrown I missed the name tag. this will give the relationship. I edited my answer above.